# Give an example of an (complex) orthogonal matrix that isn't unitary and vice versa.

Tags: matrices

Can you give the simplest example you could think of please.

I'm kind of collecting such awkward examples at the moment and have collected quite a few concerning e.g. normal matrices that aren't unitary or hermitian etc. but I'm having trouble getting examples as in the question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I only know the term "orthogonal matrix" applied to real matrices; I assume that in applying it to complex matrices you intend to require $O^\top O=1$ as for real matrices.

A matrix that is unitary but not orthogonal is $\pmatrix{\mathrm i}$.

A matric that is orthogonal but not unitary is $\displaystyle\frac1{\sqrt3}\pmatrix{\mathrm 2&\mathrm i\\\mathrm i&-\mathrm 2}$.

Comment: Yes I do mean that. Thanks for the examples!