# Does $AA^T = A^TA$ imply that A is normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A is  $n\times n$ matrix over complex numbers. Does $AA^T = A^TA$ imply that A is normal? If not what will be a counterexample?

Comment: Since one definition of a normal matrix is one that satisfies $AA^\ast=A^\ast A$, you just need a matrix where $AA^T=A^TA$, but $AA^\ast\not=A^\ast A$.

Comment: yes this is my definition of normal matrix

Answer (score 3):

No this isn't true.

Recall the definition:

> Let $A^* = \bar{A}^\mathrm{T}$ denote the conjugate matrix of $A$. Then $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n,n}$ is called normal if $AA^* = A^*A$.

We can easily see that the matrix (taken from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/383201/290074)) $A = \pmatrix{ 2&i\\i&-2}$ is orthogonal because

$$AA^\mathrm{T} = \pmatrix{ 3&0\\0&3} =A^\mathrm{T}A,$$

but

$$AA^* = \pmatrix{ 5&-4i\\4i&5} \neq \pmatrix{ 5&4i\\-4i&5}  = A^*A.$$

Comment: sorry made mistake in asking question.

Comment: What was the mistake?

Comment: I just asked whether it will be normal. But I need to ask whether it will be similar to a normal matrix

Comment: It would be better to ask a new question and leave this one in its original form than to change the current question.  Therefore, the question and answer pair will make sense.